# How to edit data in flexigrid

Tags: jquery, edit, flexigrid

I don't want to pop up a dialog to implement this.I mean I need inplace editor.

Comment: Can you give us some context?

Comment: I guess it's because the lack of context... What is `flexigrid`? what is the DOM structure? why do you need it? how can I find the `flexigrid`? If all of those were here, it's still off-topic in SO, which isn't a recommendation service. **Good luck with your problem!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find a way to do this.
Using jquery.editinplace
The following is my codes:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.editinplace.js"></script>
```

```js
function editDescription(celDiv, id){

    $( celDiv ).click( function() {
    var idTd = $(celDiv).parent().parent().children()[1];
    $(celDiv).editInPlace({
        url: "http://localhost:8081/kaimei/update_description",
        params: "address="+$(idTd.children).html(),
        error:function(obj){
        alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
        },
        success:function(obj){
        var str = m[JSON.parse(obj).status+""][window.curLanguage];
        alert(str);
        $("#displays").flexReload();
        }
    });
    });
}

$(document).ready ( function() {

    $("#displays").flexigrid (
    {
        url: 'http://localhost:8081/kaimei/load_displays',
        method:'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        width: 400,
        height: 300,
        colModel : [
        {hide: '勾选', name: 'check', width: 30, sortable: true, align: 'left'},
        {display: 'ID', name: 'id', width: 90, sortable: true, align: 'left'},
        {display: '描述信息', name: 'description', width: 110, sortable: true, align: 'left',process:editDescription},
        {display: '状态', name: 'status', width: 20, sortable: true, align: 'left'}
        ]
    }
    );  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might check this out? http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_edit_flexgrid_control.html

Comment: I am using flexigrid instead of flexgrid.